# Ansible read variable from external file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am storing all variables in json format in a external file and trying to read in the playbook
Here's an example
file

```
{out_file: exp_app_20.xml,  control_file: export_control.xml  }
{out_file: exp_app_21.xml,  control_file: export_control.xml }
```

Now when I am trying to read the variables **out_file** and **control_file** I am not able to find a suitable way to read it .
I have tried with_items and with_lines but no luck

```
- name: searching for text file

  gather_facts: false
  vars:
   host_tgt: TGT

  hosts: "{{ host_tgt }}"
  tasks:



  - name: get the file contents
    shell: cat /dir/export.prop
    register: my_items

  - debug:
      var: my_items

  - name: Export 
    shell: echo {{ item.out_file }} **---error**

    with_items: my_items.stdout_lines

    register: find_output

  - debug:
      var: find_output
```

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: That is not a valid JSON file.

Comment: Change it to "{
 "out_file": "exp_app_14.xml",
 "control_file": "export_control.xml"
}" ..still no luck while reading item.out_file

Comment: So you CAN change the file, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can change the format of the file....

```
{
  "array": [
    { "out_file": "exp_app_20.xml", "control_file": "export_control.xml" },
    { "out_file": "exp_app_21.xml", "control_file": "export_control.xml" }
  ]
}
```

Then in your playbook, load the file with `include_vars`....

```
  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: /home/jack/test.json
        name: my_items

    - debug:
        var: my_items

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.out_file }}"
      with_items: "{{ my_items.array }}"
```

That gives this output:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_items": {
        "array": [
            {
                "control_file": "export_control.xml", 
                "out_file": "exp_app_20.xml"
            }, 
            {
                "control_file": "export_control.xml", 
                "out_file": "exp_app_21.xml"
            }
        ]
    }
}

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "exp_app_20.xml"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "exp_app_21.xml"
}
```

Comment: getting the following error : "fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/data2/informatica/rudra/ansible/infa/item3.yml': line 21, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:"